# Beginner question about first-order logic

Tags: first-order-logic

In first order logic, is it correct to say that:

$\vdash\forall x(A\rightarrow B)\rightarrow\forall xB$ if and only if $\vdash\forall x(\neg A\rightarrow B)$

The right-to-left is easy to argue for. I think that the other direction should hold too but I'm struggling to find the argument. Thank you!

Comment: [This](https://www.umsu.de/trees/#(~6x(A~5B)~5~6xB)~4(~6x(~3A~5B))) might help. (It's a link to a tree proof generator.)

Comment: Please use more descriptive titles.

Comment: Hint: $p\rightarrow q, \neg p\rightarrow q \vdash q$.

Comment: Please include an explicit argument to the `right to left` direction; this will help us see what kind of argument you intend to use for the other direction. Please also include what you have done so far for the `left to right` direction.